# Скопировать сайт

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер помогите пожалуйста для примера взял сайт https://www.metallbaza.ru/ и скопировал его (да пропали некоторые элементы но это не критично), успешно выложил на  хостинг бесплатный(s419600.smrtp.ru), но не могу разобраться это главная - https://www.metallbaza.ru/ но при нажатии к примеру на кнопку о компании то перебрасывает на https://www.metallbaza.ru/about/,
а на скопированном главная под s419600.smrtp.ru и так же при нажатии переходит на https://www.metallbaza.ru/about/ а требуется чтоб на осталось моём(скопированном сайте оставался) как это можно реализовать, ну чтоб дописывалось пример:s419600.smrtp.ru/about/. Сайт копировал CTRL +S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это очень долго реализировать, когда сайт имеет много страниц. Но все же нужно  найти такие называемые теги `<a></a>`(в коде HTML) изначально у вас будет

```
<a href='https://www.metallbaza.ru/about/'>Про компанию</a>
```

А вам нужно изменить на

```
<a href='about/'>Про компанию</a>
```

Надеюсь помог!

Comment: Спасибо да то что нужно, но теперь у меня есть ещё вопрос как на хостинге создать ну эту вкладку или как это делается расскажите пожалуйста просто первый раз с html сталкиваюсь)

Comment: Чтобы оно так было, еще не знаю я тоже новичок )) Но есть один способ - это создать новый файл (например about.html) И скопировать все содержимое https://www.metallbaza.ru/about/ в этот файл. Потом заменить это все на `<a href='about.html'>About company</a>`. Если я правильно понял вопрос

Comment: я тоже об этом думал только как это на хостинге организовать не могу понять ну сейчас посмотрю. Спасибо!!

Comment: Вот сформулировал как добавить на хостинге адрес www.s419600.smrtp.ru/about/

Comment: `<ul id="menu"><li><a href="/about/">О компании</a><i class="icon"></i><ul id="menu-dropdown"><li><a `  это код и там уже так и есть  что делать?

Comment: Как на чистом html это добавить хз. А вот на фреймворках (по типу Django, ASP.NET, Flask и т.д.) можно

Comment: А ещё вопрос как это называется, просто я даже не знаю что гуглить.

Comment: Add url path html

Comment: Спасибо сейчас буду гуглить.